# Can't get a response from a public API (in React.js)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am new to React.js and I have been working on a simple form. I send the form data using ajax but I can't get a response. When I run it, it gives me **readystate is not 4**, on the console, which I have put there for debugging. I don't know where am I going wrong. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Field, Form, actions } from 'react-redux-form'
import classes from './SignUp.scss'


export class SignUp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(user) {

    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    const somePromise = new Promise((resolve) => {

         console.log(user);            
         this.setState({}, this.sendFormData);

    });

    dispatch(actions.submit('user', somePromise));    

  }    

  sendFormData(){


    var formData = {
      fn: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.fn).value,
      ln: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.ln).value,
      city: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.city).value,
      //rlc: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.rlc).value
    };

    //for check boxes
    formData.yes = this.getSelected('yes');
    formData.no = this.getSelected('no');

    // Send the form data.
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var _this = this;
    xmlhttp.open('POST','http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && response.status == 'OK') {
          console.log('success');              
        }

        else{
          console.log('failure')              
        }

        console.log('readystate is 4')
      }
      else {console.log('readystate is not 4')}
    };


    xmlhttp.send(this.requestBuildQueryString(formData));
  }


  requestBuildQueryString(params){

    var queryString = [];
    for(var property in params)
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        queryString.push(encodeURIComponent(property) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[property]));
      }

    return queryString.join('&');

  }

  getSelected(fieldName) {
    var i;
    var fields = document.getElementsByName(fieldName);
    var selectedFields = [];
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      if (fields[i].checked === true) {
        selectedFields.push(fields[i].value);
      }
    }
    return selectedFields.join(', ');

  }

  render() {


    let { user } = this.props;

    return (

      <Form model="user" onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>

        <div>
          <Field model="user.fname">
          <label>First Name: </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder= "First Name" ref="fn"/>
          </Field>
        </div>


        <div>
          <Field model="user.lname">
          <label>Last Name: </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ref="ln"/>
          </Field>
        </div>

        <div>
          <Field model="user.live">
          <label>Where do you live? </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your City" ref="city"/>
          </Field>
        </div>

        <div>
          <Field model="user.relocate" ref="rlc">
          <label>Are you willing to relocate?</label>
          <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Yes" ref="yes" checked={user.relocate.value === 'Yes'}/> Yes
          </label>

          <label>
          <input type="radio" value="No" ref="no" checked={user.relocate.value === 'No'}/> No
          </label>
          </Field>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button type="submit">
          Lets go, {user.fname} {user.lname}!
          </button>
        </div>
      </Form>
  )
  }
}

SignUp.propTypes = {
    dispatch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: React.PropTypes.shape({
    fname: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    lname: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    live: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    relocate: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,

  }).isRequired,
};

export default SignUp;
```

And this is the output on my console:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WeCO.png)

Comment: there is nothing to do with react and your ajax request. Please ensure the data you are sending is proper format. in send() the data should be in serialized form data.

Comment: Doesn't works even if I don't send any data. I should get a response whether I am sending data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do it in the correct order:

1. construct
2. open
3. set handler
4. send

you are setting handler before opening

Also,

"[Note: The onreadystatechange event is triggered five times (0-4), one time for each change in readyState.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)"

So if you see 'readystate is not 4' a few times before eventually 'readystate is 4', it's ok

**EDIT:** try replacing, if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && response.status == 'OK') with if (xmlhttp.status == 201). Your host returns status code 201

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627433/why-is-xmlhttprequest-readystate-not-equal-to-4 it says here that it matters

Comment: Ohhh.. I tried that but it didn't work. There's some other problem.

Comment: use this site to ensure that your host url is working fine: http://requestmaker.com/

Comment: your host returns stuff on GET but id=11 on POST

Comment: Host URL is good. Still giving me the same output. I have attached a screenshot of my console.

Comment: Yes but it goes to 'ready state is not 4' for 2 times, then it gets 'ready state is 4' and still goes to 'failure' part.

Comment: but then that means, you should look at the xmlhttp.status not being OK part, and not the readystate part

Comment: try replacing, if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && response.status == 'OK') with if (xmlhttp.status == 201)

Comment: I tried that before leaving workplace and yes that worked. :)